# Cannot start host WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

i followed this guide and build WCF project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

My client connect successfully from local and from remote machine and all this while run wcf service from Visual studio.
After install the service on the machine and try to start the service (from services.msc) the service not started and received an error while try to start the service:

```
service on local computer started and stopped. some services stop automatically if they are not used by other services
```

This is my On `Service1.cs` from `WindowsService project`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WcfServiceLibrary1;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1: ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null; 

        public WCFServiceHost1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
            }
            myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is from windows Event Viewer:

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source Service1 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.CreateHttpGetEndpoints(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase host, ServiceMetadataExtension mex)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at WindowsService1.Service1.OnStart(String[] args) in d:\WCFService\WindowsService1\Service1.cs:line 30
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Add some logging and catch and log the exceptions.

Comment: How can i get this errors ?

Comment: Use the windows event viewer

Comment: Can i have example how to do it (i am an new developer) ?

Comment: Start -> Run -> type "eventvwr" -> Windows logs -> Application. then search for the error

Comment: `The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address` is your error

Comment: @user2813889 how are you defining your service behaviours? in code or config?

Comment: add the following to your configuration <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>

Comment: @yakiro that will only work if he is declaring his declaring his bindings etc from config. If he is building the host from code then adding to the config will have no effect.

Comment: App.config added, i didn't tutch it in code

Comment: @user2813889  `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>` ->  `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>` as it says in the link you provided at Step 2.7

Comment: After changed this i cannot connect to the service and received ConfigurationErrorException

Comment: I would be inclined to copy the config section in the tutorial you are following and see if that works. You probably have introduced an error when editing the file.

Comment: Ok it working now but still cannot start the service from window although i have changed serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False

Comment: I suggest you to recreate your sample project from the beginning. Just ignore the msdn document and build your own wcf sample. It is really easy you can do it. First create a `Windows Service Application`. Then add a `WCF Service` to that application. It will automaticly create the config file. Then you will again put your code above which hosts the service. And always use try-catch blocks and log the errors in order to see your mistakes easly.

Comment: Problem solved and the service running now, but if i run the service from windows services i cannot connect with my client and received EndPointNotFoundException (from local and from remote machine) and with visual studio it works fine, what could cause this ?

Answer (score 1):

Goto Control Panel-> Programs and Features - > Windows Features
Inside Windows Features check for Microsoft .NET Framework -> ( For Web HTTP) Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation ,
For TCP,MSMQ Windows Communication Foundation NonHTTP Activation 
I believe they should be enabled for self hosting WCF.

Comment: Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation is already enabled

Comment: Are you using TCP service?

Comment: I am sorry i really don't know, i just followed the guide, if u want some information just ask and i will add

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
```

to:

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWcfService));
```

or

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService.Service1));
```

The `Service1` is your `Windows Service class` as I understand. In order to host your WCF service, you have to put your WCF service's class name.

Comment: My wcf class name is Service1

Comment: @user2813889 Then try to use `myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService.Service1));`