# Client cannot connect host WCF service only if the service running from windows services

Tags: c#, wcf

Continue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004338/cannot-start-host-wcf-service) post
I created `WCF` Project host service on my machine from this tutorial:
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/introduction-to-wcf-wcf-tutorial-wcf.html
After my `WCF` service run on my machine i cannot connect with my client to my service and received `EndPointNotFoundException` (this happen from local and from remote machines) and this is not the case if my service running through visual studio.
what could cause this error ?

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: How do you host the service?

Comment: What do you mean ? maybe Account = NetworkService ? look here at step 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

Comment: So you self-host your WCF service in a Windows Service. At what URL do you make it accessible? Does it use your `app.config`? Is the port accessible through the firewall?

Comment: My baseAddress = "h t t p://localhost:8733/Service1/" and even from my local machine i cannot reach my server so i don't think open port will help, correct me if i wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should run Service under administrator privileges. Windows services already have that's why you can run it without problem.